# Eclipse plug-ins. How to programmatically access to workspace preferences?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse, I need to access "*Preferences > General > Appearance > **Colors and Fonts***" programmatically.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want access the colors and fonts that have been defined? What, exactly, do you want to do?

Comment: Well, I just want to know what values are defined in the system. How I can to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This preference page defines entries in the current theme color and font registries.

Get the current theme with:

```
ITheme currentTheme = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getThemeManager().getCurrentTheme();
```

Get the registries with:

```
ColorRegistry colorRegistry = currentTheme.getColorRegistry();

FontRegistry fontRegistry = currentTheme.getFontRegistry();
```

Individual colors and fonts are accessed using the key defined in the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` `colorDefinition` or `fontDefinition` entry. Some of the most common ids are defined in `JFaceResources`:

```
Color color = colorRegistry.get("color id");

Font dialogFont = colorRegistry.get(JFaceResources.DIALOG_FONT);
```

You can also get the set of defined keys:

```
Set<String> fontIdKeys = fontRegistry.getKeySet();
```

You get the font name from the `FontData` for the font:

```
FontData [] fontData = dialogFont.getFontData();

String fontName = fontData[0].getName();
```

Comment: But what about font name?

Comment: If I want to use the theme's color for my view, I need to specify a font color and a background color. How do I know which color id I'm looking for?

Comment: @Sadik On modern versions of Eclipse most of the styling is done using the CSS support not the older registries. In a plug-in your view should pick up the themes colours by default. Ask a new question with more details if this isn't happening.